# Make window of app to be inactive in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, on-screen-keyboard

I want to make a on-screen keyboard by WPF application. I want to make my window of app to be inactive. When I use Form application development I use this code

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams param = base.CreateParams;
        param.ExStyle |= 0x08000000;
        return param;
    }   
}
```

but in WPF I don't know how to do that.

Comment: what do you mean by inactive? not focused?

Comment: I mean that when i am clicking on buttons the program to be inactive to can add text to other program.  For Example when i want to add text to any text box in any program when i open the on-screen keyboard to add text by clicking buttons

Comment: I want to make on-screen keyboard and for that i want to set my window inactive when use it because other program has the input type.